# Fragment View is Null When Called From Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity and its child Fragment with a `LinearLayout` that I generate buttons inside of. When the fragment is created, everything runs fine. However, when the parent activity downloads a new item, I call the method in the fragment that is used to generate the buttons and add them to the view, but the `LinearLayout` returns null and I can't figure out why. I either need to fix it or find a way to "re-display" my fragment. Here is the related code:

**SongFragment**:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song, container, false);
    linearLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.songFragmentMainLayout);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    RefreshButtons();
}

public void RefreshButtons(){
    linearLayout.removeAllViews(); //this line is where the NullPointerException is called
    ...
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
                    //refresh fragment view
                    SongFragment fragment = (SongFragment) sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
                    if(downloadQueue.size() == 0){
                        fragment.RefreshButtons();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "New songs downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

...

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new SongFragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Songs";
                case 1:
                    return "Playlists";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your use case allows it quickest "fix" would be to increase pager adapter offscreen view limit to be equal to item count, this will prevent fragments view from being destroyed but might cost some extra memory.

Comment: @Pawel I don't think the view is being destroyed because it's on the screen when the code is called

Comment: @EthanShoe Can you add the code from your getItem() method in sectionsPagerAdapter

Comment: @Vince sure, just did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `fragment.RefreshButtons();` returns an **NPE** because if you implemented `SectionsPagerAdapter` like you should, `getItem()` returns a new Instance of that fragment which is not yet attached to the fragment manager, therefore causing a `Nullpointer exception`.

So what you should do is get a **currently active fragment** instance like this:

```
 Fragment frag = (Fragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager, 0);
```

`0` is the position of your fragment, so for example if you have 3 fragments, `0` will return the first fragment instance etc...